# Installed version: N/A

Tags: laravel, powershell, vagrant, homestead

Help solve the problem with powershell.

I use as a console git bash. VT-x enabled. Hyper-v disabled.
Problem in

```
The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

  Installed version: N/A
  Minimum required version: 3
```

Installed powershell 6.
The error usually occurs when entering

```
vagrant ssh
```

or

```
vagrant up
```

It's funny that the problem is solved by re-entering **vagrant up** or **vagrant ssh**.

What is the problem ?

p.s. Sorry for bad English :)

Comment: This seems to be a bug with vagrant. Apparently if you do `powershell -Command 'vagrant up'` then you can `vagrant ssh` as normal.

Comment: Theo, thanks, so far it works fine. Commands are now faster executed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Theo solved the issue for us.

```
powershell -Command 'vagrant up'
```

Executing `vagrant ssh` next works as expected AND is also a little faster.